# How to perform a POST request with session data to an endpoint within the server node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I am working on `express` and I need to perform a POST request to an endpoint within the server. My code for this is :

```
request({
  url : 'http://localhost:3000/api/oauth2/authorize',
  qs:{
    transaction_id:req.oauth2.transactionID,
    user:req.user,
    client : req.oauth2.client
  },
  headers:{
    'Authorization':auth,
     'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  method:'POST'
},function(err,res,bo){
  console.log("Got response with body :"+bo);
});
```

`localhost` is the current server, this works properly but the session data is lost when i perform the POST request.
Is there any other way to perform a POST within the same server or to save the session data such that it is maintained after the POST?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintain session data in express js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39992379/maintain-session-data-in-express-js)

Comment: @Svabael: That question is now deleted

Answer (score 0):

Well, typically you register your routes something like:

```
var handlePostRequest = function(req,res,next) {
    // process req.body etc.
};
app.post('/api/oauth2/authorize', handlePostRequest);
```

If you want to call that endpoint from within your application, you simply call `handlePostRequest()` providing the `req, res, next` objects as well.

Assuming `handlePostRequest` is in global scope, or required already; in your example that would be:

```
app.get('/some/other/endpoint', function(req,res,next){
    // override the default req.body with your supplied data
    req.body = {
        transaction_id: req.oauth2.transactionID,
        user: req.user,
        client: req.oauth2.client
    };

    // you may also override req.headers etc. for authorization
    // ...

    // then call the "api" again with the new values
    return handlePostRequest(req,res,next);
});
```

IF you however strictly want to make a POST request (for some reason), you need to supply the sessionID as well, which will be in your cookie. Then the session data will be available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! in my situation, i want to strictly make a POST request, but after the POST, the session ID changes and is treated as a new session, how can i retrieve the previous session, please help, I've been stuck on this for 2 days

Comment: My suggested solution would suit your needs better. But read the end of my post, which explains how you will maintain the session.

Comment: Similar to how you have suggested , my routing is like this :                            // Create endpoint handlers for oauth2 authorize
router.route('/oauth2/authorize')
  .get(authController.isAuthenticated, oauth2Controller.authorization)
  .post(authController.isAuthenticated, oauth2Controller.decision);                              I need to first implement GET to this endpoint, get a transaction id and then post with that transaction id within the same session.